# Не получается передать данные из базы данных в новую активность

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-intent

В главной активности есть метод:

```
public void buttonRandomnicity(View view){

        try {
            DBHelper mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(new UploadText());
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();//чтение базы данных

            Cursor cursor = db.query("textTable",
                    new String[] {"name", "text"},
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[] {Integer.toString(1)},
                    null, null, null);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RandomRecord.class);
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME));
            String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT));

            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("text", text);
            startActivity(intent);

            cursor.close();
        }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
    }
}
```

Он должен передавать данные в следующую активность:

```
public class RandomRecord extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvView;
    TextView tvView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_record);

        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameRand);
        tvView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UpTextRaand);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

        tvView.setText(name);
        tvView2.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Но, по какой-то причине этого не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне с этим делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод необходимо изменить следующим образом:

```
public void buttonRandomnicity(View view){

        try {
            DBHelper mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();//чтение базы данных

            Cursor cursor = db.query("textTable",
                    new String[] {"name", "text"},
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[] {Integer.toString(1)},
                    null, null, null);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RandomRecord.class);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String name = cursor.getString(0);
                String text = cursor.getString(1);

                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("text", text);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
    }
```